# Async API call inside an infinite while loop using Axios in NODE JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, axios

Let me begin by saying that I am a beginner to Asynchronous JavaScript and it took me quite a while to wrap my head around the concept.

Now, coming to the situation at hand. I wanted to write a code that would automatically detect text from a folder containing multiple screenshots using an OCR API, whose documentation can be found here : https://ocr.space/OCRAPI

The OCR uses two engines which can produce different results. The code should run with the default engine specified and display the contents. If the result is satisfactory, the user can chose to move on with the next screenshot, or make another api request with a different engine.

I tried to use an infinite while loop to achieve this:

```js
const fs = require("fs")
const imageToBase64 = require("image-to-base64")

const apikey = "helloworld"
let engine = 1

fs.promises
  .readdir("./screenshots")
  .then((files) => {
    for (const file of files) {
      while (true) {
        console.log("Making an API Request")

        imageToBase64("./screenshots/" + file)
          .then((res) => {
            const form = new FormData()
            form.append("base64Image", "data:image/jpeg;base64," + res)
            form.append("OCREngine", engine)

            axios
              .post("https://api.ocr.space/parse/image", form, {
                headers: { apikey, ...form.getHeaders() },
              })
              .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data.ParsedResults[0].ParsedText)
                /*Code to ask the user whether the result is satisfactory or not.
                  if yes, break out of the while loop, otherwise change the engine and make the request again*/
                engine = 2
              })
              .catch((error) => console.log(error))
          })
          .catch((error) => console.log(error))
      }
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

The infinite while loop appears to continue the execution and not wait for the user input.
Can anyone help me out with the correct method of implementing this idea?

Comment: How will the user be able to "say" whether they're satisfied?

Comment: You will need to use `async`/`await` in your loop to make it sequential.